# Matlab variable name: input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions

Tags: matlab, identifier

I 'm using this `720_15_LDP_OFF_values` as matrix name in `Matlab 2015b` but I get the following error:

```
The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

Comment: MATLAB has no problem with underscores in variable names. Can you please post your code for others to verify?

Comment: Thank you @rahnema1 That solves my problem. Please add it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: can you make the first character a letter  in your matrix name @ Zinon ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MATLAB [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html):

> A valid variable name starts with a  *letter*  ... .

But your variable started with a digit.